# How do I see console.log output from Safari debugger attached to an ios WkWebW HybridWebView implementation?

Tags: javascript, ios, xamarin, safari, wkwebview

I have a [hybridwebview implementation](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView) but can't seem to get any console.log trace info when attached to the web runtime via the Safair debugger.

I can debug the same js in my hybridwebiew on the Android project, but no matter what I do I get no console output for the iOS project.

The safari debugger even pops up when my HybridWebView loads … but I can't see any js assets loaded nor any console log output.

To be clear, the client-side js is running because I'm getting (some) of the anticipated behavior, but I can't debug or even trace without console.log (or some alternative?).  Any help appreciated.

Comment: How can you pop a safari debugger in a Xamarin.Forms control? Can you share some code to describe your issues? Are you deploying a web app or mobile app?

Comment: I'm using a "HybridWebViewRenderer" like: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/hybridwebview/  

There is a way to use the platform-specific browser for each as described:

Android: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-debugging-webview/

and 

iOS: https://raygun.com/blog/debug-javascript-mobile-safari/

Android works but on the iOS project, running on MacOS, the Safari desktop browser there *does* open when I hit the webview in the app on the simulator.  But Safari doesn't show any associated html/js assets nor connect.